# Making attribute constant

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am passing array of data from parent component to child component, in child component i am filtering data based on category selection(selection is separate with list of available categories).

Now i created another attribute to copy the attribute value from parent but on change of the original attribute automatically the copy attribute is getting changed.

I want to keep the copied attribute always constant which i copied first.

Here is my code

**Passing from parent**

```
c:child1 temp ="{!v.parentX}"
```

**child component**

```
aura:attribute name="temp" type="Product2[]"
aura:attribute name="copyX" type"Product2[]" default="{!v.temp}"
```

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: can you add more code like how did you fill the data in to `parentX` and where u using `onchqange` event

Comment: I have a parent component where i am doing search, the search results i am passing to child component as an attribute. now i want to create 2 attributes both will have same search results which is coming from parent. Later i need to do some operations on data, so i need one attribute always constant and other one changeable.